# Exception in thread "IDL" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no idl_ips in java.library.path

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, idl-programming-language

I'm trying to run IDL on linux, but the result is

```
Exception in thread "IDL" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no idl_ips in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at com.rsi.idldt.core.ips.IPS_Access.<init>(IPS_Access.java:44)
    at com.rsi.idldt.core.ips.IPS_Access.get(IPS_Access.java:51)
    at com.rsi.idldt.core.ips.IPS_Manager$3.run(IPS_Manager.java:482)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It seems like I have to install *idl_ips* but in the web I found only a version of *idl_ips.dll* for windows.

I'm sorry, maybe is simple but I am a beginner.

Can you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might check [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2309188.html), which describes a very similar-looking problem. In that post, it's *lib*idl_ips from libXp which is missing, but it looks like different flavors of Linux have slightly different dependencies. The other poster linked to [this IDL help page](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Support/SelfHelpTools/HelpArticles/HelpArticles-Detail/TabId/2718/ArtMID/10220/ArticleID/16146/IDL-fails-to-install-on-Linux-What-to-do.aspx), which provides instructions for specific Linux installations.

Comment: ok, thanks.
It turns out that _idl_ doesn't need java, while _idldl_ does. So, using _idl_, I dont't need anymore to fix this problem.